# Show SQL results in ListBox

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I would like to show a query in a listbox. Here is what I have to far:

```
private void PopulatePeople()
{

    string query = "SELECT Name FROM People WHERE KnownFrom = KSOK";//@KnownFrom";

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KnownFrom", listBox1.SelectedItem);

        DataTable PeopleDT = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(PeopleDT);

        listBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";//+"Surname";
        //listBox2.ValueMember = "Id";
        listBox2.DataSource = PeopleDT;
    }
}
```

At this point it says, that there is no column `KSOK`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `KSOK` is the string you are searching for, then you need to quote it:

```
string query = "SELECT Name FROM People WHERE KnownFrom = 'KSOK'"
                                                       // ^    ^ quotes
```

Comment: You may need to add an Id to the query  eventually.  Like "Select PeopleId as Id, Name FROM People..."

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use Parameters, like you had commented out, you can do the following (using ListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() to get the value from the UI):

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KnownFrom", ListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()); //Edited to use value from UI.
```

Then, add the @ variable to your query string for KSOK:

```
string query = "SELECT Name FROM People WHERE KnownFrom = @KnownFrom";
```

Comment: KSOK is, apparently, the value they want to search by, to the variable name should be `@KnownFrom`.

Comment: Edited to reflect KSOK being the search string.  Thanks.

Comment: yes, KSOK is the string, but I would like to get that string from a listbox.
but listBox2.SelectedValue doesnt work.

Comment: That is because SelectedValue is not the text that is in the box.  The text you see in the box comes from ListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString(). I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I just found out about the ToString. Now it doesnt chrash, but I guess somewhere in the middle the data gets messed up or something. Doesnt display anything. Oh yeah, and its listBox1.SelectedItem (sorry). I display distinkt KnownFrom in listBox1, and I want to show data with the selected KnownFrom in listBox2.

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
string query = "SELECT Name FROM People WHERE KnownFrom = KSOK";
```

to

```
string query = "SELECT Name FROM People WHERE KnownFrom = 'KSOK'";
```

When you have string literal as part of your queries, they should be wrapped by single quotes `'`.